# A gamma function identity

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, gamma-function

I am given the impression that the following is true (for at least all positive $\lambda$ - may be even true for any complex $\lambda$)

$$ \left\lvert \frac{\Gamma(i\lambda + 1/2)}{\Gamma(i\lambda)} \right\rvert^2 =  \lambda \tanh (\pi \lambda) $$

It would be great if someone can help derive this.

Comment: $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$ correct?

Comment: I guess the question is answered now below. One thing though, my attempt was using $\Gamma(x+y)=\dfrac{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(y)}{\mathrm{Beta}(x,y)}$, which makes all Gammas then cancel. This means $\mathrm{Beta}(i\lambda,\tfrac{1}{2})^{-2}$ is simple, but I couldn't evalute it.

Answer (score 8):

Using the [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z},$$
we get (for **real** $\lambda$)
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12+i\lambda\right)}{\Gamma(i\lambda)}\right|^2&=
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12+i\lambda\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12-i\lambda\right)}{\Gamma(i\lambda)\Gamma(-i\lambda)}=\\
&=(-i\lambda)
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12+i\lambda\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12-i\lambda\right)}{\Gamma(i\lambda)\Gamma(1-i\lambda)}=\\
&=(-i\lambda)\frac{\pi/\sin\pi\left(\frac12-i\lambda\right)}{\pi/\sin\pi i\lambda}=\\
&=-i\lambda\frac{\sin \pi i \lambda}{\cos\pi i \lambda}=\\
&=\lambda \tanh\pi \lambda.
\end{align}
This will not hold if $\lambda$ is complex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I have correct the factor of $\pi$ in the question. So you seem to be using an identity like $\Gamma(z)^* = \Gamma(\bar{z})$ - why is this true? (..or am I missing something something terribly basic!?..)

Comment: @user6818 For instance, gamma function has the following integral representation: $$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{ \infty} t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt=\int_0^{ \infty} e^{-t+(z-1)\ln t} dt , $$ from which we can deduce $\overline{ \Gamma(z) }=\Gamma( \bar{z} )$.